# SAS Execute sql strings with a macro

Tags: sql, sas

Ive a table that have attributes for lib, table and some SQL strings that i want to execute with a macro to get some statistic data over that other tables and update my original table with it.

```
 %macro busca_parametros;

    proc sql noprint;
        select 
            livraria,
            tabela,
            tot_colunas,
            sql_tot_linhas,
            sql_sum_num,
            sql_min_data,
            sql_max_data
        into
            :livraria1-,
            :tabela1-,
            :tot_colunas1-,
            :sql_tot_linhas1-,
            :sql_sum_num1-,
            :sql_min_data1-,
            :sql_max_data1-
        from libx.tablex;
    quit;

    %do i = 1 %to &sqlobs; 
        proc sql noprint;
            update libx.tablex
        set 
            tot_linhas=&&sql_tot_linhas&i.,
            sum_num=&&sql_sum_num&i.,   
            min_data=&&sql_min_data&i.,
            max_data=&&sql_max_data&i.
        where livraria=&&livraria&i. 
            and tabela=&&tabela&i. 
        quit;
    %end;

%mend;

%busca_parametros
```

Im getting this error (image link below) on all the macro variable ranges from one of the strings that have a count(*) on it, and i dont know why.
Anyway i really dont know if this works, since i cant make it run,
Help appreciated, tks in advance.

[log SAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMddb.png)

Comment: Post some sample data.  Is there a reason you are not doing a `left join`?  Your example shows `libx.tablex` in two query contexts.  Where is the *other* table.  There are no aggregate funtions nor `group` clause. Are your statistics precomputed?

Comment: Tks for your interest Richard, my libx.tablex, have fields like libname and table name, fields with sql strings (eg. "proc sql; select count(*) from libY.tableY; quit;" and other fields to write down the results. The macro ideia is read each line of my libx.tablex, get the sqls strings from each record, execute them and update the table with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set statements need to be in parentheses if they include an in-line query.

```
tot_linhas = (&&sql_tot_linhas&i.),
sum_num    = (&&sql_sum_num&i.),   
min_data   = (&&sql_min_data&i.),
max_data   = (&&sql_max_data&i.)
```

For example:

```
data have;
    set sashelp.cars;
run;

proc sql;
    update have
    set horsepower = (select count(*) from sashelp.class)
    ;
quit;
```

Comment: Tks Stu, but dont work for me. I want to execute that sql string (eg. "proc sql; select count(*) from libY.tableY; quit;") and get his result to update my have table. I dont want to update my have table with the string itself.

Comment: If  just write in my macro the code %do i = 1 %to &sqlobs; &&sql_tot_linhas&i.;%end; i get my count result, but how can i update my table with that result ?

Comment: The code posted above is what the in-line query will do to update the table and appears to be what your code is trying to do. `Set` writes a single value to a variable. That value can be the results from an in-line SQL statement such as `select count(*) from libY.tableY`. You do not need to do a separate `proc sql` statement.

Comment: Tks again stu, iam now having the error in my where clause in the proc sql update  "ERROR: The following columns were not found in the contributing tables: libY, tableY.", dont know why, since that values exists in the columns "livraria" and "tabela". Any ideia?

Comment: Got it. add to reinforce the strings with double quotes like this: where livraria="&&livraria&i." and tabela="&&tabela&i."; Tks for all insights Stu.